# How to call a jsp page in a popup from JS

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-mvc

I tried with windows.location but it opening in new tab. But i want to open it as pop up. I tried with:

```
function update(expenseId){
    alert("test" + expenseId);
    window.location.href("/jsp/user.jsp","height=400,width=400");
}
```

but this also throwing window.location.href not a function error. please help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change or adop it to your function

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var myWindow = window.open("/jsp/user.jsp", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function update(expenseId){
   alert("test"+expenseId);
   popup_window = window.open("/jsp/user.jsp","height=400,width=400");
   popup_window.focus();
}
```

Comment: it opens like in new browser window.. but i want to open like simple popup in iframe or modal popup